# overflow-y для таблицы

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Можете пожалуйста добавить overflow-y: auto; в tbody, чтоб thead оставался на месте. Пытался сделать, но не работает скролл. Просто игнорируется. Убрал свои попытки скролл сделать, чтоб мусора небыло

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('https://i.yapx.ru/RR1P1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #fbfbfb;
    text-decoration: none;
}

input.search {
    width: 440px;
    height: 34px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #4f4f4f;
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: url('https://i.yapx.ru/RR1P2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px center;
}
input.search::placeholder {
    color: #a0a0a0;
}
input.search:hover {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
input.search:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fbfbfb;
    background-color: #DF005B;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #c71a5f;
}
button:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid #9c194d;
}


/* Nav */

.nav {
    height: 84px;
    margin: 9px 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.avatar {
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: translateY(10px);
    margin-left: 7px;
}


/* Main */

.wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 700px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 24px 48px;
}

.title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    padding: 8px;
}

tr {
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

td, th {
    border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

th {
    text-align-last: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-size: 17px;
}

td {
    font-size: 15px;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.info-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #afafaf;
}

.black {
    font-weight: bold;
    color:  black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <title>Список DataBase</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="nav">
            <div>
                <a href=""><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="150"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">Sea#1475 <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/RR1Pq.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"> <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/RR1Po.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <article class="wrap">
                <div class="title">
                    <div class="item">
                        <h1>База данных</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Найти..." class="search">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                            <button>ОБЪЯВИТЬ В РОЗЫСК</button>
                            <button>СОЗДАТЬ ЗАПИСЬ</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Сотрудник</th>
                            <th>Жетон</th>
                            <th>Структура</th>
                            <th>Задержанный</th>
                            <th>Паспорт</th>
                            <th>Статьи</th>
                            <th>Розыск</th>
                            <th>Под залог</th>
                            <th>Дата события</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6322</td>
                            <td>FIB - CTD - 142993</td>
                            <td>752</td>
                            <td>FIB</td>
                            <td>Roy Unicorn</td>
                            <td>34145</td>
                            <td>10.8</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 00:04:25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6325</td>
                            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
                            <td>661</td>
                            <td>LSCSD</td>
                            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
                            <td>41574</td>
                            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>Да</td>
                            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <footer class="footer">
                    <div class="info-item">Всего задержаний: <span class="black">7 267</span></div>
                    <div class="info-item">Задержаний за месяц: <span class="black">975</span></div>
                    <div class="info-item">Задержаний за день: <span class="black">10</span></div>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: с таблицами такой номер не пройдет - это таблица, а не див. все известные лично мне рабочие решения включают в себя возню с яваскриптом, который либо отслеживает ширину ячеек одной таблицы (например, хедера) и применяют их к другой таблице (боди), либо отслеживает прокрутку таблицы в контейнере и сдвигает `<thead>` на соответствующее число пикселей вниз-вверх с помощью `transform:translatey(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с `position: sticky`, которое предложил Просто Miha, очень интересное, но в нём есть нюанс: при скролле пропадает хедер с кнопками и поле поиска. Чтобы этого не происходило, можно использовать две таблицы - одну как thead, а другую - как tbody. Единственное, что при таком решении нужно задавать явную ширину ячейкам, чтобы они не съезжали в разных таблицах относительно друг друга:

```css
.thead {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 1300px;
}
.thead td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tbody {
  height: 280px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  min-width: 1300px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 10%;
  word-break: break-word;
}
.table td:nth-child(1),
.table td:nth-child(3),
.table td:nth-child(6),
.table td:nth-child(8),
.table td:nth-child(9){
  width: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thead">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>#</td>
      <td>Сотрудник</td>
      <td>Жетон</td>
      <td>Структура</td>
      <td>Задержанный</td>
      <td>Паспорт</td>
      <td>Статьи</td>
      <td>Розыск</td>
      <td>Под залог</td>
      <td>Дата события</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="tbody">
  <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>6322</td>
        <td>FIB - CTD - 142993</td>
        <td>752</td>
        <td>FIB</td>
        <td>Roy Unicorn</td>
        <td>34145</td>
        <td>10.8</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 00:04:25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6325</td>
        <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
        <td>661</td>
        <td>LSCSD</td>
        <td>Lay Halseys</td>
        <td>41574</td>
        <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Да</td>
        <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю правильно ли я вас понял или нет, но вот моё решение

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('https://i.yapx.ru/RR1P1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

input.search {
  width: 440px;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: url('https://i.yapx.ru/RR1P2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px center;
}

input.search::placeholder {
  color: #a0a0a0;
}

input.search:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

input.search:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  background-color: #DF005B;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #c71a5f;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid #9c194d;
}


/* Nav */

.nav {
  height: 84px;
  margin: 9px 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.avatar {
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  margin-left: 7px;
}


/* Main */

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 700px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 24px 48px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: -24px;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 8px;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

td,
th {
  border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

th {
  text-align-last: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 17px;
}

td {
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.info-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #afafaf;
}

.black {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div>
      <a href=""><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="150"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="">Sea#1475 <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/RR1Pq.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar"> <img src="https://i.yapx.ru/RR1Po.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <article class="wrap">
      <div class="title">
        <div class="item">
          <h1>База данных</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Найти..." class="search">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <button>ОБЪЯВИТЬ В РОЗЫСК</button>
          <button>СОЗДАТЬ ЗАПИСЬ</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Сотрудник</th>
            <th>Жетон</th>
            <th>Структура</th>
            <th>Задержанный</th>
            <th>Паспорт</th>
            <th>Статьи</th>
            <th>Розыск</th>
            <th>Под залог</th>
            <th>Дата события</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>6322</td>
            <td>FIB - CTD - 142993</td>
            <td>752</td>
            <td>FIB</td>
            <td>Roy Unicorn</td>
            <td>34145</td>
            <td>10.8</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 00:04:25</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6325</td>
            <td title="[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [LSCSD-SRT-135767]">[LSCSD-SRT-135767], [L...</td>
            <td>661</td>
            <td>LSCSD</td>
            <td>Lay Halseys</td>
            <td>41574</td>
            <td>10.8, 12.7</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Да</td>
            <td>2022-03-01 08:15:32</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="info-item">Всего задержаний: <span class="black">7 267</span></div>
        <div class="info-item">Задержаний за месяц: <span class="black">975</span></div>
        <div class="info-item">Задержаний за день: <span class="black">10</span></div>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Не совсем то,  чтоб скролиись только записи в tbody https://i.yapx.ru/RR3oU.png